# How to use php and mysql functions inside javascripts

Tags: php, javascript

Here is my javascript code which is added in the  tag of my php/html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $('#status').change(function(){

           var status = $('#status').val();                  
           var html = ''; //string variable for html code for fields 

           if( status=="closed"){

               html += '<th>Close By :</th><td align="left"><select name="close_by">'+<?php $user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
                        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($user)){?>+'<option value="'+<?php echo $data['username'] ?>+'">'+<?php echo $data['username']; ?>+'</option>'+<?php } ?>+'</select></td>'; 
            }

            $('#close_by').html(html);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The code is for that, if Status=="closed" then a select tag will be appeared and the option values will be fetched from the database using mysql functions.But its not working. Please help to sort out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to learn more about server-side VS client-side

Comment: Try Ajax. Look up "jQuery ajax"

Answer (score 1):

You can't. PHP/MySQL reside on your server, while JS is executed in the browser.

Of course you may let the browser interact with your server by proper [HTTP requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), after setting [proper routes on your server](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife).

Comment: I am not very expert in this side. So please provide me some ways that how i could be able to do that. Or What i have to use now. Thanks

Comment: Get some nice book / online resource, and learn how the web works : )) That is not something you can do in one day of course, so take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix PHP into Javascript.  The PHP will execute on the server, and then the JS on the client.  It's horrible though, extremely bad practice, and a nightmare to debug.  Much better to seperate them out and use jQuery ajax to load the data.

Or use PHP to put the data into a JSON object at the start of the javascript, and process that with Javascript, rather than using PHP code to concatenate strings inside Javascript.

But in your example, what exactly is the problem?  What is the end result of the PHP (in the HTML source) of the `html` variable?  I suspect there's a bracket or quote wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('#status').change(function(){

       var status = $('#status').val();                  

       if( status=="closed"){
          $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php?',//if you have parameters
                success:function (response) {
                    $('#close_by').html(response);
                }
            });          
       }
    });
});
```

And you create a new php file for the ajax request
ajax.php

```
<th>Close By :</th>
<td align="left">
    <select name="close_by">
        <?php $user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($user)){?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $data['username'] ?>"><?php echo $data['username']; ?>     
                 </option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
```